# How to setup Heroku Scheduler without Rails?

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

Reading the documentation here, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler, I see how to schedule tasks with rails. But I was wondering how to schedule tasks with regular ruby?

What do I have to put in the task field to have my ruby script run?

Comment: Erm, it has "For apps built on other frameworks or languages…" right in that document you linked.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add a [Rakefile](http://rake.rubyforge.org/files/doc/rakefile_rdoc.html) to your regular ruby app, and run `rake task_name` via the scheduler.

Comment: I tried creating a file called rakefile.rb and placed it in lib/tasks/. When I called rake :task_name I received an error sayng unable to locate rakefile, rakefile.rb, or Rakefile.rb, ...etc

Comment: You'll need a "Rakefile" file in your application root.  You might also be able to just setup a basic ruby script, like task.rb, and then type "ruby task.rb" in the Heroku Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if once upon a time you had to use rake, but no more. Just use ruby directly:

```
ruby path/to/yourfile.rb arg1 arg2
```